# MAMP / Slim PHP still have 404 error

Tags: mamp, slim

I'm using MAMP PRO and Slim PHP framework.
Here is my project structure :

- htdocs

  - myapp

    - api

      - index.php
      - .htaccess

My .htaccess :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

If I try with Postman a GET request on :
localhost:8888/admin 
I get a 404 and this error in apache logs :
[error] [client ::1] File does not exist: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/admin
But with this :
localhost:8888/myapp/api/index.php/admin 
It works...

I'd like to do my request on this url :
localhost:8888/admin

I've try many things... RewriteBase, configure VirtualHost, ...
Can you help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Apache configuration set your document root to `/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/myapp/api`.